# how can i set array in EKRecurrenceRule for day of the week?

Tags: ios, swift, dayofweek, ekevent, ekrecurrencerule

- i want to add event on every week in specific day selected by user. it can be one or more or may be all day.
- i'm storing day value selected by user in model class variable.
- But when i adding event and select days suppose today is monday and i select Tuesday and Wednesday and save it. then i check in iphone calendar it added in Monday and Wednesday.
- i cant understand this problem, even i debug my code i get right value for day selection in model class variable then why result different ?
- Suggest me any solution or idea.

**Thanks**

```
  var days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek]()


        if routineData.routine_monday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.monday)]
        }
        if routineData.routine_tuesday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.tuesday)]
        }
        if routineData.routine_wednesday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.wednesday)]
        }
        if routineData.routine_thursday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.thursday)]
        }
        if routineData.routine_friday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.friday)]
        }
        if routineData.routine_saturday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.saturday)]
        }
        if routineData.routine_sunday == 1 {
            days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.sunday)]
        }


        let rule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .weekly, interval: 1, daysOfTheWeek: days as? [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek], daysOfTheMonth: nil, monthsOfTheYear: nil, weeksOfTheYear: nil, daysOfTheYear: nil, setPositions: nil, end: nil)

        event.addRecurrenceRule(rule)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **work perfectly**
- Here, its simple to add specific day in Recurrencerule in
  dayOfTheWeek.
- i take one mutable-array and add weekday in mutable array as per my
  condition.
- In my case, i save user selected day in model class variable suppose if user select Monday and Wednesday then i save it as monday = 1 and wednesday = 1 in model class variable[e.g : routinedata.routine_monday = 1].
- and i set that mutable-array in dayOfTheWeek. see below code.

  ```
      let tempDays = NSMutableArray()

      if routineData.routine_monday == 1 {

          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.monday))
          //days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.monday)]
      }
      if routineData.routine_tuesday == 1 {
          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.tuesday))
      }
      if routineData.routine_wednesday == 1 {
          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.wednesday))
      }
      if routineData.routine_thursday == 1 {
          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.thursday))
      }
      if routineData.routine_friday == 1 {
          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.friday))
      }
      if routineData.routine_saturday == 1 {
          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.saturday))
      }
      if routineData.routine_sunday == 1 {
          tempDays.add(EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.sunday))
      }
      print("day selected\(tempDays)")


      let rule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .weekly, interval: 1, daysOfTheWeek: tempDays as? [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek], daysOfTheMonth: nil, monthsOfTheYear: nil, weeksOfTheYear: nil, daysOfTheYear: nil, setPositions: nil, end: nil)

      event.addRecurrenceRule(rule)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the days as an array of EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek like

```
let days = [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek]()
```

Or you should cast `NSMutableArray` to expected argument type `[EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek]`

```
let rule = EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWith: .weekly, interval: 1, daysOfTheWeek: days as? [EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek], daysOfTheMonth: nil, monthsOfTheYear: nil, weeksOfTheYear: nil, daysOfTheYear: nil, setPositions: nil, end: nil)
```

Comment: Can you debug and check for Tuesday and Wednesday whether it is executing the expected if condition or not?  And here what is routineData? I guess if check fails and causing the issue.

Comment: routineData is my model class object. but its ok i had solved my problem by my own self. added my solution below.